# How to activate GRASS GIS 7 plugin in QGIS 2.8?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, grass-7.0, qgis-grass-plugin

Apparently, my linux ubuntu setup of QGIS doesn't contain grass gis, although when I initially installed it last week I added grass gis to the command line. Anyway, I typed in once again and installed grass gis 7.0, however while GRASS starts, the plugin QGIS for it doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Linux to offer any suggestions. We do have a [number of questions about GRASS and Ubuntu](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=grass+ubuntu) though with a smaller [subset specifically mentioning plugin](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=grass+ubuntu+plugin). You might find a solution in one of those.

Comment: 1. From which repository did you install? 2. Which QGIS version are you running? As far as I know, the GRASS plugin for GRASS7 in QGIS is not yet available at the moment, but there is a crowd founding initiative going on http://www.gissula.eu/qgis-grass-plugin-crowdfunding/ and it will surely land in the next QGIS version or is already ín master. BTW: Those kind of question should better go to the qgis-user mailing list, cause both Q & A will be outdated very soon...

Comment: So, I might as well install the 6.4.3 version. Would it be compatible with QGIS 2.8? Anyhow, it's not on my windows version either.

Comment: Didn't use the grass plugin for ages, cause most grass functions I need are already in the processing toolbox. So I can't tell you more of this.

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GRASS 7 is not compatible with QGIS 2.8.

You can follow the development of the new GRASS plugin on http://www.gissula.eu/qgis-grass-plugin-crowdfunding/progress.html.

For 2.8, you will need to install GRASS 6.x.

Comment: Is GRASS 7 compatible with QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon?

Comment: Here is some help for newer QGIS versions: https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/the-qgis-grass-plugin-is-back/

Comment: Thanks markusN, is this your blog? Some useful stuff on it for ecologists alike.
@underdark Grass 7.0.3 is compatible with QGIS 2.8.1 Wein on my system, atleast. The website you suggest does not have an update on this however.

Answer (score 3):

A late answer:

QGIS 2.14 is compatible with GRASS 7 now. On Windows, the standalone installer provides separate icons for GRASS 7.0.3 integration. For GRASS 6.4.3 support, you have to stick to QGIS 2.12 or older. Windows versions can be installed in parallel without harm.

On Linux, you have the option to choose support for GRASS 6 in the `debian` packages, or GRASS 7 in the `ubuntugis` packages. The latter is only available up to Ubuntu trusty (running on Linux Mint 17.3 too).

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I'm still using 2.10, but I'm going to upgrade soon.