# Automated Viewshed in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed

I want to create a workflow with a QGIS script where I need a viewshed tool. There is a really cool [viewshed plugin](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/viewshed). Unfortunately I am not able to access it in the QGIS console. I also found out that [GRASS GIS 7.0](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.viewshed.html) and SAGA GIS have viewshed tools. But I am not able to access them in QGIS.

Do you have an idea how I can use a viewshed tool in a QGIS script?

Comment: As an FYI, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148351/ has a comment that indicates the GRASS7 QGIS plugin is not yet available. I don't know anything more, just remembered seeing that a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it is not too late for you but this is how you can get access to Grass 7 and SAGA tools in QGIS.
NB. I am using QGIS 2.8

1. Ensure that SAGA, Grass 7 and msys are installed in your PC and that they (Grass and SAGA) are running.
2. Run Grass 7 (directly by double clicking the Grass icon or through QGIS plugins menu) and set up a new mapset. (This sets up the working environment for GRASS which is a requirement to use it). After this it is not necessary that GRASS is still open and you may close it.
3. Go to Processing Menu - Options - Providers. Configure the paths for the GRASS and SAGA folders as well as msys folder to point to the installation directories respectively.

for example as show in the graphic below.

[image]