# Can't access GRASS tools in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm running QGIS 2.6 on OSGeo-Live 8.4 Virtual Machine based on Lubuntu 14.04.

I've set up a GRASS (GRASS GIS 7) environment in QGIS, and I have a merged .tif file of LiDAR images open in QGIS, so I want to use the grass tools to read the LiDAR image. Both the "grass tools" menu option and symbol are not highlighted and I can't select them (but some Grass tools are available such as add Grass raster/vector layer). What am I missing? How can I access the Grass tools?

Answer (score 2):

The question is essentially a dupe of https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/150497/687

In short: the upgrade development to GRASS GIS 7 is work in progress and will be shipped (to my knowledge) with QGIS 2.12.