# Cannot locate GRASS plugin in QGIS 2.14.1 on Linux

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, linux-mint, qgis-grass-plugin

I am trying to load the GRASS plugin in QGIS but it is not shown in the plugin manager (no matter if I turn on experimental and deprecated plugins). Under processing / options / providers GRASS GIS 7 commands and GRASS commands are visible and activated.

I am running Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa. QGIS 2.14.1 (after upgrading from 2.8. where I had the same problem), GRASS 7, and the qgis-plugin-grass (version 1:2.14.1+20trusty) are installed.

I have read this post [How to activate GRASS GIS 7 plugin in QGIS 2.8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148351/how-to-activate-grass-gis-7-plugin-in-qgis-2-8). There it is said that QGIS 2.8 is not compatible with GRASS 7. Therefore I installed QGIS 2.14, which should be compatible (http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog212/index.html?highlight=grass#feature-update-of-the-grass-plugin).

Some more information.
I get this errors in the QGIS plugin log:

Failed to load /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassplugin6.so (Reason: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassplugin6.so: (libgrass_gis.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

Failed to load /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassprovider6.so (Reason: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassprovider6.so: (libgrass_gis.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

Failed to load /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassrasterprovider6.so (Reason: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassrasterprovider6.so: (libgrass_gis.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

So, it seems QGIS looks for Grass 6 plugins while Grass 7 is installed. I can set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but then the Plugin (6) does not match Grass (7). In /usr/lib/qgis/plugins only the lib...6.so are available. How can I get the 7?

Comment: It is no duplicate because it is about another version of QGIS for which, as far as I understand, the plugin should be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qgis.org/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages only contains packages for grass6, while http://qgis.org/ubuntugis/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages supports grass7 only.

You might have to [compile QGIS from source](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Compiling-QGIS-with-GRASS-Plugin-td5253057.html), or remove the debian packages from your Linux, and switch to the ubuntugis ones.

While this works for trusty (and Linux Mint 17.3),  there are currently no ubuntugis packages for newer Ubuntu versions **and** Grass 7 support.

Comment: That was exactly the information I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: By now, the ubuntugis stable also has support for QGIS 2.8.3 and Grass 7. But I can't see from the file description which grass version is supported by the plugin.