# Missing v.stream.order of GRASS in QGIS processing tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I want to use v.stream.order of GRASS in QGIS for stream but it is not available in QGIS processing tool.
How to add that in processing tool

QGIS version
2.14.17-Essen

Comment: Do you have GRASS 7 enabled and running for other commands?

Comment: No .I have grass plugin installed with QGIS while installing QGIS.

Comment: What operating system do you have? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: So, your question is possible duplicate of this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190355/cannot-locate-grass-plugin-in-qgis-2-14-1-on-linux?rq=1