# QGIS Cloud - partial display of polygons only

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

I'm attempting to upload a layer of polygons (land zoning). The output in QGIS cloud has significant geographical gaps in some areas. The source data is not sound however. I'm using a free account but are well under the MB limit. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Upload to where? and how? Why do you say the source data is not sound? If you have bad geometries there are ways to find/fix if these are causing gaps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148350/cleaning-polygon-after-using-dissolve-to-repair-geometry-in-qgis should help there.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the msg.  I should have stated that the source data is sound.  Polygons that appear offline just seem to disappear through the upload process