# Avoiding/getting rid of topological errors after dissolve?

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, topology, dissolve

After dissolving a layer in QGIS 2.8, I get *a lot of* topological errors in the new (dissolved) layer. Any suggestions as to how to get rid of these errors without manually editing each one?

[image: Screenshot:]

**update:**

trying to use [@Josephs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph) suggestion I get a strange error message:

[image: log]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97986/ though it may be the best solution is in a comment on my answer rather than the answer itself. In addition to rmdangle you might consider rmarea. cc @joseph Also, another term that may help in researching is sliver polygon - I can't tell if your errors are polygons or just holes. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/ for approaches from a variety of software.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of remove dangles you can correct the original layer. 
Use v.clean like Joseph says but run the tool v.clean.snap on your original borders layer, set the tollerance (for borders I think you can use a big value but you have to try) and then try again to dissolve.

You can find eventualy remaining dangles using Topology Checker and "Must not have gaps".

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the GRASS function *v.clean* and selecting the **rmdangle** which aims to remove any annoying dangles. You could access this from the *Processing Toolbox*.

[image: v.clean interface]

You can set the "threshold" option which determines what dangles can be deleted:

> The rmdangle tool deletes a dangle if the (combined) length is shorter than thresh or thresh < 0. If the combined length is larger than thresh, nothing is deleted.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it does not work for me, see error-message in my screenshot above.

Comment: That error probably depends by some strange (german) chars inside data. Set the codec of the shape to UTF-8 (using plugin "shapefile encoding fixer") and look at your table for find some errors (you see a black "?") correct them and retry.

Another, easier, way is try to import into grass the layer and after that using the tool inside grass with the grass plugin.

Comment: @Sergio - That's a good point, very well picked up!

Comment: @Sergio: At the end I fixed the errors manually. But thanks for your hints- the will hopefully be helpful in future-projects. And of course your are right, that it is better to fix the original layer that the final (dissolved) one ....

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked: processing toolbox > 'Delete Holes' and run without any minimum area.